# How to get Json Raw Body in magento Controller?

Tags: php, json, magento

I am creating a magento controller in which I want to receive json raw data which is being sent from cURL.

Data is being posted on magento controller in json format via post method.

I am trying to access this data but not getting anything.

I am using this code to get the data.

```
   public function CreateproductsAction()
       {

       $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); 

          print_r($data);exit;        
            }


      }
```

Output is blank. Please suggest me the right way to get the data..

Comment: I would recommend creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][1] as per Stack Overflow's question guidelines.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the raw body method.

```
public function CreateproductsAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody(); 
    print_r($data);exit;        
}
```

Comment: It works, even though at first inspecting $this->getRequest() shows _raw_Body as null.

Comment: That will not work, use `$this->getRequest()->getContent()` instead